# Is there a Python editor with python built in?

Tags: python, editor

I need an editor with python built into it. Currently I use blender so I do not have install python. Blender comes with the python32.dll to use python. is there another editor out there that I can execute python commands without it being installed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What IDE to use for Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Comment: Why do you not want to install Python?

Comment: @closers: This question is not answered by that one. That question doesn't cover whether the editor/IDE ships with the runtime environment.

Comment: Do you really want to write programs that you'll only ever run in the editor?

Comment: @katrielalex: In some environments installing programs is not allowed/possible -- although it *is* strange that it would be OK to install an editor...

Comment: I cannot install. i do not want to carry a jump drive with me everywhere and portable python seems to be too bulky in size, I was just curious if there were a simple editor that uses the dll or if someone could teach me how to use the dll

Comment: @Jacob Valenta: According to PortablePython website, "Installed size: based on selected packages, between 47MB and 63MB". I don't think that you can buy a 128Mb flash drive anywhere today.

Comment: @Jacob Valenta: So you can't install Python, but you can install an editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViennaMike referenced Movable Python which has a small fee, after I had asked the question, I did more searching and found movable python about the same time he suggested it. I seems to find something different.

http://code.google.com/p/movable-python/

this seems to be a free version of movable python. This is only the IDLE portion of python, but can be used to run *.py files. It is considerably smaller than a normal python installation, and comes in a zip file.

Several people asked about my ability to install an editor but not python. At my High school (I work with the IT dept as one of my classes) I find python helps a lot with some tasks. I am unable to install python due to admin rights (which I will have next year) so anytime I did install python, because of its size on the Network drive, it would be automatically deleted.

Thank you ViennaMike again for finding movable python, unfortunately, it only works with python 2.5, so I may see if there is a way I can get that to 3.2

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question fully either. Why NOT install python? But if the question is how to be able to edit and run python on machines without installing it, there's Movable Python (http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/movpy/) with a small fee to purchase and Portable Python (http://www.portablepython.com/wiki/About), free, donation requested.  I've used Movable Python and can vouch for it.  I've never tried Portable Python.